# Css class Word match on preg_match

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the following regex:

```
\w*(\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+[-_]+)?careerfy([-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)\w*
```

The above should match the css classes which include the word **careerfy** and it's variants:

1. Match .crfy-careerfy
2. Match .careerfy
3. Match .careerfy-post
4. Match .crfy-careerfyds-add-space

The match 4 is not expected and not required!

See https://regex101.com/r/ncd4V9/3

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you showed a sample of the css file, so we know what else to avoid(for people like me who don't know the css format well)

Comment: Sorry, updated https://regex101.com/r/ncd4V9/3

Comment: Match `careerfy` as a whole word,  `\w*(\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+[-_]+)?careerfy\b([-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)\w*`, see 
 https://regex101.com/r/ncd4V9/4

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this will not match .careerfy_post

Comment: It is not in the requirements, please add it to the question. Try `(?![^\W_])` instead of `\b`. See https://regex101.com/r/ncd4V9/5

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That works great !   Please post your solution so i can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom word boundary after the `careerfy` word:

```
\w*(\.([a-zA-Z0-9]+[-_]+)?careerfy(?![^\W_])([-_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]+)?)\w*
                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ncd4V9/5).

The `(?![^\W_])` will not let match `careerfy` if it is followed with a letter or digit.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5Cw*(%5C.(%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B%5B-_%5D%2B)%3Fcareerfy(%3F!%5B%5E%5CW_%5D)(%5B-_%5D%2B%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%2B)%3F)%5Cw*):
[image]

[image]